# RaspberryPi Pico SPI and nrf24l01

Tags: spi, nrf24l01+, raspberrypi-pico

I am programming a RaspberryPi Pico with the Arduino IDE. Works pretty well, but now I try to control an nrf24l01 module.

My code compiles but I do not know on which pins the SPI bus has to be hocked up. I tried to connect to different pins according the pinout
https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/pico/Pico-R3-A4-Pinout.pdf
(for example 2 sck, 3 miso, 4 mosi), but nothing worked so far.

Does anybody know what the default pins are or how to control them? I also would like to control other SPI hardware, for example a display.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

const uint64_t address = 0x1;
byte sendData[1];


#define CSN_PIN  5
#define CE_PIN   6
RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN); 

byte counter = 0;
 
void setup()   
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(“radio starting");

  if (!radio.begin()) 
  {
    Serial.println("radio hardware is not responding!!");
    while (1) {} 
  }  
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
}

void loop()   
{
  Serial.print("Counter: ");
  Serial.println(counter);
  
  sendData[0] = counter;
  
  radio.write( sendData, sizeof(sendData));
  
  counter++;
}
```

Comment: Did you successfully run it both transmission and receiving? Any capacitor you use? My experience is that when using Raspberry Pi Pico + NRF24L01 and on Micropython, it works BUT fails when programmed on Arduino

Answer (score 4):

1. For Arduino-pico core

   ** MISO - pin GP16

   ** MOSI - pin GP19

   ** CS   - pin GP17

   ** SCK  - pin GP18
2. Arduino-mbed core

   ** MISO - pin GP4

   ** MOSI - pin GP3

   ** CS   - pin GP5

   ** SCK  - pin GP2

Comment: Fantastic, it works!

Comment: Source, and other pins hard-coded on the pico: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-mbed/blob/8e0a044330e88bde781eb4c509875ce94980659f/variants/RASPBERRY_PI_PICO/pins_arduino.h